# How to add custom events to tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I have a tornado application that will serve data via websocket.
I have a separate blocking thread which is reading input from another application and pushing an object into a Queue and another thread which has a blocking listener to that Queue.

What I would like is for the reader thread to somehow send a message to tornado whenever it sees a new item in the Queue and then tornado can relay that via websocket to listening clients.

The only way I can think to do this is to have a websocket client in the reader thread and push the information to tornado via websocket. However it seems that I should be able to do this without using websocket and somehow have tornado listen for non websocket async events and then call a callback.

But I can't find anything describing how to do this.

Comment: What OS? If Linux then it sounds like a job for epoll. Then you get sent an event when some output becomes available. You can get rid of the queue then.

Comment: It is cross platform, mainly running on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, all you need to do is call `IOLoop.add_callback` from the thread that is reading from the queue.  This will run your callback in the IOLoop's thread so you can write your message out on the client websocket connections.